# Открытие браузера c#

Tags: c#

Как открыть браузер при нажатии на кнопку с указанным URL в textBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      string url = "http://" + textBox1.Text; 
      Process.Start(url); 
}
```